# How to reverse after zip two chains

Tags: rust

I have the following code which does not compile.

```
fn main() {
  let a =
    "123"
    .chars()
    .chain("4566".chars())
    .zip(
        "bbb"
        .chars()
        .chain("yyy".chars()))
    .rev()
    .map(|x, y| y)
    .collect::<String>();
  println!("Hello, world! {}", a);
}
```

Got error like following:

```
src/main.rs:37:10: 37:15 error: the trait `core::iter::ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for the type `core::iter::Chain<core::str::Chars<'_>, core::str::Chars<'_>>` [E0277]
src/main.rs:37         .rev()
                        ^~~~~
src/main.rs:37:10: 37:15 error: the trait `core::iter::ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for the type `core::iter::Chain<core::str::Chars<'_>, core::str::Chars<'_>>` [E0277]
src/main.rs:37         .rev()
                        ^~~~~
src/main.rs:38:10: 38:23 error: type `core::iter::Rev<core::iter::Zip<core::iter::Chain<core::str::Chars<'_>, core::str::Chars<'_>>, core::iter::Chain<core::str::Chars<'_>, core::str::Chars<'_>>>>` does not implement any method in scope named `map`
src/main.rs:38         .map(|x, y| y)
```

My understanding is `rev()` method is defined in `Iterator` as where it implements trait `DoubleEndedIterator`

```
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self> where Self: DoubleEndedIterator { ... }
```

Also `Zip` implements this trait:

```
impl<A, B> DoubleEndedIterator for Zip<A, B> where B: DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator, A: DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator
```

So the problem is `Chain` doesn't implement `ExactSizeIterator`. But how do I work around this?

I tried to add `.take()`  for both chains to convert the type to `Take` which implements `ExactSizeIterator`, but Take doesn't implement `DoubleEndedIterator`.

Note this is a simplified example. In reality I cannot reverse both chain first and then do the zip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the following impl (spoiler: it doesn't exist):

```
impl<A, B> ExactSizeIterator for Chain<A, B>
  where A: ExactSizeIterator, B: ExactSizeIterator { ... }
```

An `ExactSizeIterator` must implement only one method, `len(&self)`. So the idea behind an hypothetical implementation would be to sum both lengths so that `chain_a_b.len() == a.len() + b.len()`.

The [reason it doesn't exist](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/chain-is-not-exactsizeiterator/1506) is that Rust cannot guarantee that this addition (`usize + usize`) will not overflow. Thus it forbids it. It sounds like a little strict, but that's the status quo for now, unfortunately.

Worse: even if this impl actually existed, you would run into the fact that `Chars` is not an `ExactSizeIterator`, so it would still not work.

An alternative (probably not the only one) would be to collect the chains into a vector. Bad because of the memory allocation, but if it isn't a perf bottleneck it could be worth the tradeoff.